# Looking for software with similar complex number functionality to Grapher on OSX

Tags: complex-analysis

Currently I use either windows or linux (linux preferred). I would like to have some sort of software that can graph complex number expressions like:

$$ |w| = |w-1| \text{ OR } \left|\dfrac{1}{z+i}\right| = 1$$.

Comment: Try WolframAlpha online.

Comment: @xbh WA online isn't really that good for plotting IMO. One has very limited control over the plot, and it's very small. Geogebra is, if not perfect, at least better.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for your information!

Comment: I have used both geogebra and wolfram and I havent't found a lot of functionality for complex plots.